# NSIS weird behavior with GetParameters

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I'm having a weird error with NSIS:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "FileFunc.nsh" # To use GetParameters

Name nsDialogs
OutFile nsDialogs.exe



Function .onInit
 ${GetParameters} $R0
  MessageBox MB_OK "$R0" 
FunctionEnd

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

Section
    DetailPrint "hello world"
SectionEnd
```

If I use this command line

```
nsDialogs.exe /d=hello
```

the message box says: "/d=hello" as expected, but if I use

```
nsDialogs.exe /D=hello
```

the message box says "" and this is wrong.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2):

> /D sets the default installation directory ($INSTDIR), overriding
>   InstallDir and InstallDirRegKey. It **must be the last parameter** used in
>   the command line and must not contain any quotes, even if the path
>   contains spaces. Only absolute paths are supported.

This means you cannot use /D with `${GetParameters}` (/S and /NCRC are also switches used by NSIS). NSIS by design uses **everything after** /D= as `$instdir`.

The only way to detect /D is to not use `InstallDir[RegKey]` in your script and check if `$instdir` is != "" in `.onInit`

Answer (score 0):

`/D` is command line parameter that let define the installation directory directly from the installer command line invocation.

See the [Installer usage / Common Options](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#3.2) chapter for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I assume that NSIS strips out its inbuilt parameters by default. In that case you could try something like this:

```
!define myInstDir "$PROGRAMFILES\myApp"

Function .onInit
    ${GetParameters} $R0
    StrCpy $R0 ${myInstDir} +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "$$INSTDIR was changed on runtime"
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: yes but it also strips out everything from the command line parameter. Is this an NSIS bug?

Comment: what do you mean by everything?